# Balance payments bank account verification

Tags: php, balanced-payments

I know that the call to initiate a bank account verification using the [Balanced](https://www.balancedpayments.com/) payments [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is:

```
$bank_account = Balanced\BankAccount::get("/bank_accounts/BA2TmACICKF9Lah8tzHWpLEx");
$verification = $bank_account->verify();
```

However, how do I get the information from the returned call and what variables do I use:

```
{
    "bank_account_verifications": [
    {
        "attempts": 0,
        "attempts_remaining": 3,
        "created_at": "2014-11-    14T19:27:13.837146Z",
        "deposit_status": "pending",
        "href": "/verifications/BZ1eMAsKt13lIj2SkvvHlxfT",
        "id": "BZ1eMAsKt13lIj2SkvvHlxfT",
        "links": {
            "bank_account": "BA17zYxBNrmg9isvicjz9Ae4"
        },
        "meta": {},
        "updated_at": "2014-11-14T19:27:13.837148Z",
        "verification_status": "pending"
    }
],
"links": {
    "bank_account_verifications.bank_account": "/bank_accounts/{bank_account_verifications.bank_account}"
}

{
    "bank_account_verifications": [
    {
        "attempts": 0,
        "attempts_remaining": 3,
        "created_at": "2014-11-    14T19:27:13.837146Z",
        "deposit_status": "pending",
        "href": "/verifications/BZ1eMAsKt13lIj2SkvvHlxfT",
        "id": "BZ1eMAsKt13lIj2SkvvHlxfT",
        "links": {
            "bank_account": "BA17zYxBNrmg9isvicjz9Ae4"
        },
        "meta": {},
        "updated_at": "2014-11-14T19:27:13.837148Z",
        "verification_status": "pending"
    }
],
"links": {
    "bank_account_verifications.bank_account": "/bank_accounts/{bank_account_verifications.bank_account}"
}
```

Comment: Is that one JSON object or two?

Comment: It's one JSON object

Comment: It's not valid. You can't have `{` right after `}`, as you have after `"links":`.

Comment: Are these supposed to be two elements of an array?

Comment: Actually I think I'm mistaken. It is two.

Comment: Yes. I was using similar code to access the array but I can't tell which variable I use to access this array.

Comment: The two JSONs look identical to me. Where are you seeing that? Most PHP APIs return an array or an object, not JSON strings. You usually only see the original JSON if you use something like `cURL` to access a web API, then you have to `json_decode` to decode it into an object or array.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this @RickGrimes?  I logged in to ask the same question.